# Не могу перегрузить оператор "<" для класса

Tags: c++, stl, перегрузка-операторов, multiset

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class student {
public:
bool operator< (student &ob2) {
        return true;
    }
    student() {
        a = 0;
        fio = "Kolesnikov Vadim Sergeevich";
        vuz = "PSU";
        fac = "Facultet";
        kaf = "Kafedra";
        f_o = "Ochka\Zaochka";
    }
    student(char *fio1, int a1) {
        a = a1;
        fio = fio1;
        vuz = "VUZ";
        fac = "Facultet";
        kaf = "Kafedra";
        f_o = "Ochka\Zaochka";
    }
    ~student() {};
    void output() {
        cout << fio.c_str() << endl;
        cout << vuz.c_str() << endl;
        cout << fac.c_str() << endl;
        cout << kaf.c_str() << endl;
        cout << f_o.c_str() << endl << endl;
    }
    void input() {
        cout << "FIO:";
        cin >> fio;
        cout << "vuz:";
        cin >> vuz;
        cout << "fac:";
        cin >> fac;
        cout << "kaf:";
        cin >> kaf;
        cout << "f_o:";
        cin >> f_o;
        cout << endl;
    }
protected:
    string kaf;
    string f_o;
    int a;
private:
    string fio;
    string vuz;
    string fac;
};


void main(void)
{
    char str0[] = "Potogin Nikita";
    char str1[] = "Sidelnikov Maxim";
    char str2[] = "Kolesnikov Vadim";
    char str3[] = "Fedoseev Gena";
    student ob0(str0,1);
    student ob1(str1,2);
    student ob2(str2,3);
    student ob3(str3,4);
    ob0.output();

    multiset<student> list;
    multiset<student>::iterator it;
    list.insert(ob0);
    list.insert(ob1);
    list.insert(ob2);
    list.insert(ob3);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Хочу добавить в контейнер multiset несколько объектов класса.
VS пишет ошибку c2803

Comment: это надо писать не комментарием, а следует внести правку в вопрос

Comment: и перегрузить надо оператор < у самого класса

Comment: пробовал, тогда выдаёт ошибку c2678. Но суть та же

Comment: значит допустили ошибку

Comment: еще, multiset принимает параметром класс для сравнения http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset, можете создать сравнивающий класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Необходимости засовывать оператор в класс не было. Наоборот, правильнее перегружать такой оператор отдельной функцией.

  В любом случае, оба параметра оператора сравнения должны быть константными

  ```
  bool operator< (const student &ob2) const {
       return true;
  }
  ```
- Оператор сравнения, который всегда `return true;` - грубое нарушение требований, накладываемых на оператор сравнения. Работать не будет.
- Что такое

  ```
  #include "iostream"
  #include "string"
  ```

  ? При включении стандартных заголовков, скобки должны быть только треугольными.
- `int main`, а не `void main`.

Answer (score 0):

### Основная ошибка

`operator<` должен принимать константные ссылки

```
bool operator< (const student &ob1, const student &ob2)
```

И, само собой, он не должен быть тривиальным.

### По мелочи

```
f_o = "Ochka\\Zaochka";
```

Бекслеши в строковых константах надо удваивать

```
int main(void)
```

`main ()` надо декларировать с `int`, а не `void` и возвращать `0`.

Answer (score 0):

нужны константные ссылки

```
bool operator< (const student &ob1, const student &ob2) {
    return true;
}
```

или использовать lamda:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str0[] = "Potogin Nikita";
    char str1[] = "Sidelnikov Maxim";
    char str2[] = "Kolesnikov Vadim";
    char str3[] = "Fedoseev Gena";
    student ob0(str0,1);
    student ob1(str1,2);
    student ob2(str2,3);
    student ob3(str3,4);
    ob0.output();

    // вместо просто возврата true, наверное должно возвращаться что-то осмысленное
    auto comp = [](const student& lst, const student& rst){ return true; };

    typedef multiset<student, decltype(comp)> myset;

    myset list(comp);
    myset::iterator it;
    list.insert(ob0);
    list.insert(ob1);
    list.insert(ob2);
    list.insert(ob3);

    system("pause");
}
```